# pyspark - Convert column string to header and values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame with four columns of strings such as:

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| z10234 | Header One : teacher | Header Two : salary | Header Three : 12 |
| z10235 | Header One : plumber | Header Two : hourly | Header Three : 15 |
| z10236 | Header One : executive | Header Two : salary | Header Three : 17 |
| z10237 | Header One : teacher | Header Two : salary | Header Three : 15 |
| z10238 | Header One : manager | Header Two : hourly | Header Three : 11 |

I need to convert each string col1, col2, and col3 such that the initial part of the string becomes the header:

| id | HeaderOne | HeaderTwo | HeaderThree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| z10234 | teacher | salary | 12 |
| z10235 | plumber | hourly | 15 |
| z10236 | executive | salary | 17 |
| z10237 | teacher | salary | 15 |
| z10238 | manager | hourly | 11 |

Answer (score 3):

You can split by colon to get the first part as the column names and the second part as the column values:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

names = df.limit(1).select(
    [F.split(c, ' : ')[0].alias(c) for c in df.columns[1:]]
).head().asDict()

df2 = df.select(
    'id', 
    *[F.split(c, ' : ')[1].alias(names[c]) for c in df.columns[1:]]
)

df2.show()
+------+----------+----------+------------+
|    id|Header One|Header Two|Header Three|
+------+----------+----------+------------+
|z10234|   teacher|    salary|          12|
|z10235|   plumber|    hourly|          15|
|z10236| executive|    salary|          17|
|z10237|   teacher|    salary|          15|
|z10238|   manager|    hourly|          11|
+------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach by creating `MapType` for each column , and exploding followed by groupby+pivot:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
columns = ['col1','col2','col3']

def fun(c):
  c1 = F.split(c,":")
  return F.create_map(c1[0],c1[1]) #Since there can only be 2 strings

out = (df.select("id",*[fun(x).alias(x) for x in columns])
         .select("id",F.explode(F.map_concat(*columns)))
         .groupby("id").pivot("Key").agg(F.first("value")))
```

---

```
out.show()

+------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
|    id|Header One |Header Three |Header Two |
+------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
|z10234|    teacher|           12|     salary|
|z10235|    plumber|           15|     hourly|
|z10236|  executive|           17|     salary|
|z10237|    teacher|           15|     salary|
|z10238|    manager|           11|     hourly|
+------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```